# subsetting dataframe in R using two criteria, one of them is regular expression

Tags: regex, r, subset

I have a dataset something like this:

```
col_a col_b    col_c
1     abc_boy  1
2     abc_boy  2
1     abc_girl 1
2     abc_girl 2
```

I need to pick up the first row only based on `col_b` and `col_c`, and then change the valye in `col_c`, which is something like this:

`df[grep("_boy$",df[,"col_b"]) & df[,"col_c"]=="1","col_c"] <- "yes"`

But the code above is not OK, since the first criteria and the second criteria do not originate from the same set.

I can do it in a dumb way by using a explicit loop, or do a "two-tier" subsetting, something like this:

```
df.a <- df[grep("_boy$",df[,"col_b"]),]              #1
df.b <- df[grep("_boy$",df[,"col_b"],invert=TRUE),]  #2
df.a <- df.a[df.a[,"col_c"]=="1","col_c"] <- "yes"   #3
df.a <- df.a[df.a[,"col_c"]=="2","col_c"] <- "no"    #4
df <- rbind(df.a,df.b)                               #5
```

But I prefer not to, can anyone enlighten me how to "merge" `#1` and `#3`? Thanks.

Comment: Give us sample output to go with the sample input, please.  It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `grepl` instead of `grep`. 
`grepl` returns a logical vector (match or not for each element of x), which can be combined with logical operators.

Answer (score 6):

The reason it is not working as you expected despite correct logic, is that you are using `grep` where you should be using `grepl`. Try instead:

```
df[ grepl("_boy$", df[,"col_b"]) & df[,"col_c"]=="1", "col_c"] <- "yes"

> df
  col_a    col_b col_c
1     1  abc_boy   yes
2     2  abc_boy     2
3     1 abc_girl     1
4     2 abc_girl     2
```

`grepl` retruns a logical vector of the length of its arguments, whereas `grep` returns a shorter numeric vector, so in this case gets recycled.