# regular expression to filter out phrase based on the last few characters in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a few phrases like below:

```
abc_xy_def
abc_xy
abc_vw_def
abc_vw
def_ab
```

I want to use regular expression to filter them into two groups: one group with `abc_` head and the `_def` tail, and another group with the `abc_` head only.

I have tried something like this:

```
> grepl("abc_[(a-z_)*][^def]","abc_xy_def")
[1] TRUE
> grepl("abc_[(a-z_)*][^def]","abc_xy")
[1] TRUE
```

But it doesn't work, can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [subsetting dataframe in R using two criteria, one of them is regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645118/subsetting-dataframe-in-r-using-two-criteria-one-of-them-is-regular-expression)

Comment: why this is a duplicate of my previous question? my previous question involves a dataframe with subsetting, but this only focuses on regex

Comment: "_def" is a constant or can be any combination like "_edf", "_fed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For capturing all of them: `^abc_[a-z]*(_def|)$`

For capturing only with `_def` tail: `^abc_[a-z]*_def$`

For capturing only without `_def` tail: `^abc_[a-z]*$`

If it's not accurate, please clarify your question.

Comment: should it be `^abc_[a-z]+(_def|)$` rather than `^abc_[a-z]*(_def|)$"`? Because the `[a-z]` in `_[a-z]` must present in my string.

Comment: yes a + will be better than a * in your case as this part of your string is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

don't know R but should this work ?

```
grepl("^abc_.+_def$","abc_xy_def")
```

it seems that you mistaken the meaning of "**[^def]**" this will match one character that is not **d** , **e** or **f** so your regexp "abc_[(a-z_)*][^def]" will match any string containing **abc_** followed by  a single character that is one of **(**, **a** to **z**, **_**, **)** or ***** followed by another single char that is not **d**, **e** or **f**

in the one i propose you here what it take

- **^** -> mean we look at the start of the string
- **abc_** will force  abc_
- **.***   macth any character (not \n) 0 to unlimited times
- **def** force def
- **$**  mean that we must be at the end of the string

if you want thoose with no _def  at end try this one: `"abc_.+(?!def)"`

Comment: I've clarify my question afterwards, I need to explicitly state that `^abc` is present in the string

Comment: then try grep1("^abc_(.*)def$","abc_xy_def")

Comment: @malko -- did you mean to rollback my edit of `grep1` to `grepl`? (The first isn't a base R function).

Comment: effectively as i don't know R i was supposing you were using grepl function. but basicly regex pattern are mostly the same i suppose, if grep1 is your handmade function it should be good to share it's code with us to know what is different from basic grep functions

Comment: `grepl` is a built-in R function that acts on a vector and returns a vector of booleans corresponding to the results of the regex. Josh was just trying to be helpful, given that you know about regex, but not about R. You answer will be more correct if you change `grep1` to `grepl` as he suggested.

Comment: yes, finally understood, this was me reading grep1 instead of grepl in the op post at the begenning sorry for the confusion